# Unmet dependencies - what to do?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mplayer : Depends: libavcodec52 (>= 4:0.5.1-1) but it is not installable or
                    libavcodec-extra-52 (>= 4:0.5.1-1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libavformat52 (>= 4:0.5.1-1) but it is not installable or
                    libavformat-extra-52 (>= 4:0.5.1-1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libjack0 (>= 0.118+svn3796) but it is not installed
           Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not installed
           Depends: liblzo2-2 but it is not installed
           Depends: libmpcdec3 but it is not installable
           Depends: libx264-85 but it is not installable
           Recommends: apport-hooks-medibuntu but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: hmmm, did u try `apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal, and run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Please be careful about what packages it removes, updates and installs. If you are sure about it, answer yes and let it do its job. If you are unsure, post the full output here and I'll try to give you some advice.

It seems that you've added a 3rd party repository that is not getting very well with your Ubuntu version.

When adding 3rd party repositories, please ensure it is for the exactly same Ubuntu version that you are running now. Also, don't trust any 3rd party repository, since they can break your system.

Comment: thanks jorge ...but this command doesn't solve the problem 
but what did you mean by adding 3rd party repositories ... i'm a beginner in ubuntu  .. can you help me?

Comment: It seems you are using medibuntu, a 3rd party repository. You can read what I'm talking about on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). Anyways, if that didn't solve the problem, please post the output by editing your first post.

Comment: ok thanks alot jorge ... i read about repositories and i solve the problem by remove the mplayer package ... is there is wrong with that??

Comment: Nope, mplayer is an optional player. Don't worry about removing it.